# How to create page with text, tables and ListView in the same page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just something like this:

[image]

I add ListView just like this:

```
this.Content = new StackLayout { Children = { header, listView } };
```

But what about text and table? What classes are correct to use in this case?

Is ContentPage is right choice for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentPage should work fine, you can see the different pages and visual examples of what they are used for in the [Xamarin documentation (Pages)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/).

"String" and "Another string" should be of type [`Label`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/)

I'm not sure if "TextCell" are labels or input, but assuming input it should be an [`Entry`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Entry/)

And your table is called `Grid`, [heres an example](https://coderwall.com/p/uwsdlw/programmatically-adding-views-to-xamarin-forms-grid) where a grid is created both programatically, and using xaml.

Reference list of: [Pages](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/), [Layouts](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/layouts/), [Views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/) and [Cells](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/cells/). Xamarin guides in the links has alot of examples and recepies of how to do things.

Generally speaking I would advice you look into creating your pages in **xaml**. And here is the [xaml basics, getting started guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/). For anything more than a static page with even 1 or 2 views it can get overly complicated to create pages programatically. Eventually you will want to have interaction or bindings which is doable programatically, but I would not recommend it.